# How do I create a acrylic blur effect in a VCL application?

Tags: delphi, vcl, dwm

How do I create a acrylic blur effect like the one in UWP apps in a Delphi VCL application?

I tried using the following method I found [here](https://theroadtodelphi.com/2009/10/26/glass-effect-in-a-delphi-console-application/):

```
program DwmTest;
//Author  : Rodrigo Ruz 2009-10-26
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils;

type
  DWM_BLURBEHIND = record
    dwFlags                 : DWORD;
    fEnable                 : BOOL;
    hRgnBlur                : HRGN;
    fTransitionOnMaximized  : BOOL;
  end;

//function to enable the glass effect
function DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(hWnd : HWND; const pBlurBehind : DWM_BLURBEHIND) : HRESULT; stdcall; external  'dwmapi.dll' name 'DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow';
//get the handle of the console window
function GetConsoleWindow: HWND; stdcall; external kernel32 name 'GetConsoleWindow';

function DWM_EnableBlurBehind(hwnd : HWND; AEnable: Boolean; hRgnBlur : HRGN = 0; ATransitionOnMaximized: Boolean = False; AFlags: Cardinal = 1): HRESULT;
var
  pBlurBehind : DWM_BLURBEHIND;
begin
  pBlurBehind.dwFlags:=AFlags;
  pBlurBehind.fEnable:=AEnable;
  pBlurBehind.hRgnBlur:=hRgnBlur;
  pBlurBehind.fTransitionOnMaximized:=ATransitionOnMaximized;
  Result:=DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(hwnd, pBlurBehind);
end;

begin
  try
    DWM_EnableBlurBehind(GetConsoleWindow(), True);
    Writeln('Test of glass effect');
    Readln;
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Unfortunately this only makes the windows a white-transparent appearance without any kind of blurring.

How can I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 3):

First, you don't need to declare the DWM APIs yourself, since they are already declared in the `DwmApi` unit. Also, `GetConsoleWindow` is declared in the `Windows` unit.

Second, the effect your code is trying to apply is *not* the UWP effect; instead, it is the Windows Vista Aero effect.

And this does work for me:

```pascal
program Project3;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  Windows, System.SysUtils, DwmApi;

function DWM_EnableBlurBehind(hwnd: HWND; AEnable: Boolean; hRgnBlur: HRGN = 0; ATransitionOnMaximized: Boolean = False; AFlags: Cardinal = 1): HRESULT;
var
  pBlurBehind: DWM_BLURBEHIND;
begin
  pBlurBehind.dwFlags := AFlags;
  pBlurBehind.fEnable := AEnable;
  pBlurBehind.hRgnBlur := hRgnBlur;
  pBlurBehind.fTransitionOnMaximized := ATransitionOnMaximized;
  Result := DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(hwnd, pBlurBehind);
end;

begin
  DWM_EnableBlurBehind(GetConsoleWindow(), True);
  Writeln('Hello, Aero!');
  Readln;
end.
```

[image: Screenshot]

So why doesn't it work for you? Probably, you are using Windows 8 or later. In these systems, this effect has been removed.

Obviously, when you found this code, your first instinct was to look up the documentation for the [`DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmenableblurbehindwindow) function. But apparently you missed the warning a page down:

[image: From MSDN: Remarks. Note. Beginning with Windows 8, calling this function doesn't result in the blur effect, due to a style change in the way windows are rendered.]

Comment: (I realise this is more of a comment. Sorry about that. At least I gave you a cute rabbit picture.)